# Many-to-Many Relationship Between Enum and Entity is Not Being Stored

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums, ef-code-first, many-to-many

I am working on a Entity Framework Code First project where I have many-to-many relationships:

Service Providers can have many Service Types, and Service Types can have many Service Providers.

Services have only one Service Type.

**Service Type** is an enum:

```
public enum ServiceTypeEnum
{
    Ambulance = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Cash Advance")]
    CashAdvance = 2,
    Hospitalization = 3,
    Hotel = 4,
    [Display(Name = "House Call")]
    HouseCall = 5,
    [Display(Name = "Medical Escort")]
    MedicalEscort = 6,
    Transfer = 7,
    Repatriation = 8
}
```

**Service Provider**

```
public partial class ServiceProvider
{
    public ServiceProvider()
    {
        ServiceTypes = new HashSet<ServiceTypeEnum>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ServiceProviderID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    // This is OK for a single Service 
    //public virtual ServiceTypeEnum ServiceType { get; set; }

    // I added this so that Service Providers can have multiple Service Types
    public ICollection<ServiceTypeEnum> ServiceTypes { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Service> Services { get; set; } 
}
```

and **ServiceProviderViewModel**:

```
public class ServiceProviderViewModel
{
    public class CreateModel
    {
        public int ServiceProviderID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> AllServiceTypes { get; set; }
        public string[] SelectedServiceTypes { get; set; }

        //public ServiceTypeEnum ServiceType { get; set; }
    }

    public class EditModel
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

}

and finally **ServiceProviderController**:

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var _allServiceTypes =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(ServiceTypeEnum))
           .Cast<ServiceTypeEnum>()
           .Select(t => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(t.ToString(), (int) t));

        var viewModel = new ServiceProviderViewModel.CreateModel()
        {
            AllServiceTypes = _allServiceTypes
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ServiceProviderViewModel.CreateModel viewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This is OK for a single Service Type
            //var serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider
            //{
            //    Title = viewModel.Title,
            //    ServiceType = viewModel.ServiceType
            //};

            // For multiple Service Types
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceProvider();
            serviceProvider.Title = viewModel.Title;
            for (int i = 0; i < viewModel.SelectedServiceTypes.Length; i++)
            {
                serviceProvider.ServiceTypes.Add((ServiceTypeEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(ServiceTypeEnum), viewModel.SelectedServiceTypes[i].ToString()));
            }

            repository.InsertServiceProvider(serviceProvider);


            repository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The problem is; there are no tables or columns in the database for the added service types. While debugging, I can see that the selected values of checkboxes are converted to respective enums and are added to serviceProvider.ServiceTypes

There's nothing when I try to get the service types:

```
repository.ServiceProviders.ServiceTypes
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You should turn `ServiceType` into an entity type mapped to a database table having (at least) an Id (primary key) and Name. It also makes you flexible in adding/removing service types without having to recompile your code.

Answer (score 1):

An enum is a struct. Only class types may be persisted. Entity Framework is rightly ignoring the "relationship". How do you imagine that an enum would be represented as a database table in the first place?

Comment: Thanks, but it is being stored in a column if the relationship is one-to-many. And as far as I know, newer ASP.NET MVC versions do support enums...?

Comment: Enums are supported, but as a single column type. You can't have a collection of enums because that would require a separate table to store "rows" of those enum values. Remember, relational databases must flatten object hierarchies. You could have an entity with that enum as a property, and then have a one-to-many with that *entity*, but not directly with an enum.

Comment: There's no reason that EF can't or shouldn't support this. You could just have the junction table and use the enum values as the 2nd column key - without having an "enum" table.